# Entity Framework 5.0 Benchmark Test

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ado.net, linq-to-entities, benchmarking

I'm doing an internship, and I've been asked to evaluate the performance changes for the new Entity Framework 5.0.
I've personally never used the Entity Framework, nor do I have any kind of big database or queries to do a proper benchmark test.

I've been doing some simple tests targeting to .NET 4.5 using for loops of LINQ queries in order to try getting the Query automatically compiled and see some kind of performance change from when I target to .NET 4.0, but I've not been able to see any kind of performance change at all.

Is there any kind of already done benchmark test for Entity Framework which could show when the new version of Entity Framework has a better performance?

Thanks

Comment: Is this what your looking for? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/14/sneak-preview-entity-framework-5-0-performance-improvements.aspx

Comment: That link just shows the results of some unexplained test. 
I would need to be able to perform the test from code, in order to evaluate on which scenarios there is any actual performance change.

Comment: Can you paste the old you are using into the question?

Comment: Like I said, I've been doing very simple loops of LINQ queries (like
  var q1 =
                    from c in context.Departments
                    where c.DepartmentID == p
                    select c;

                var department = q1.First();) but there doesn't seem to be any performance difference between .NET 4.5 and .NET 4.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Few things:

- If you want to compare performance changes between .NET 4 and .NET 4.5 you must have two machines for that because .NET 4.5 is in-place upgrade. Installing .NET 4.5 on machine will "remove" possibility to run on old .NET 4.0 (thank Microsoft for this nightmare). You can target project to .NET 4 but at runtime you will always run on .NET 4.5 if it is installed.
- Finding performance improvements can be quite difficult because there is no list of real changes in query generation but two areas which should interest you are:

  - Auto compiled queries - automatic feature in EF5 with .NET 4.5. This feature should improve subsequent execution speed of queries - first execution will be still "slow" or perhaps even "slower" than in .NET 4
  - Optimizations in Table-per-hierarchy queries. This should generally improve queries targeting just single type in inheritance structure or projecting just fields from base entity. In .NET 4 this always led to joining all tables for derived entities even if they were not needed. I didn't try this improvement yet so I will be happy to read your findings here.

Comment: Thank you, I was still thinking that when I targeted the project to .NET 4.0 it actually ran over .NET 4.0. As soon as I have some concrete test results I'll post them here.

Comment: The targeting works only for VS experience (intellisense and build) but because .NET 4.5 assemblies have the **same version** as .NET 4.0 they are used at runtime.

Comment: I don't get why Microsoft would do that. But really thank you for the tip, I expended almost all day trying to understand why there was no difference at the subsequent execution speeds with .NET 4.0 on LINQ to Entities queries if the automatic compilation was one of the major announced changes for Entity Framework 5.